# How to mock Firebase auth providers such as FacebookAuthProvider?

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-native-firebase

I am trying to mock `react-native-firebase`'s firebase.auth object so that it will return a credential to the code under test so that I can test my method.

I have the following code under test:

```
public async FacebookSignIn(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const result = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);

      if (result.isCancelled) {
        throw new Error('User cancelled request');

      }

      const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

      if (!data) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong obtaining the users access token');
      }

      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken);
      await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

I want to ensure that at the end of the function, my CUT calls signInWithCredential so I have a test case like so; `func` is a global :
`jest.fn()`

```
describe('FacebookSignIn', () => {
    it('should sign in user with facebook credentials', async () => {
      await service.FacebookSignIn();
      expect(func).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
  })
```

However with the following mock I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined`:

```
jest.mock('react-native-firebase', () => {
  return {
    auth: () => {
      return {
        currentUser: null,
        signOut: func,
        signInAnonymously: func,
        signInWithEmailAndPassword: func,
        signInWithCredential: func,
        FacebookAuthProvider: jest.fn(() => {
          return {
            credential: jest.fn(() => {
              return {
                provider: 'dummy',
                token: '1234',
                secret: '5678'
              }
            })
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I've looked at the type for `firebase.auth` and it can return this:

```
type AuthModule = {
    (): RNFirebase.auth.Auth;
    nativeModuleExists: boolean;
} & RNFirebase.auth.AuthStatics
```

which to me looks like it is mocking the signIn methods correctly, but the AuthStatics methods aren't being mocked. AuthStatics is defined as follows:

```
interface AuthStatics {
        EmailAuthProvider: EmailAuthProvider;
        PhoneAuthProvider: AuthProvider;
        GoogleAuthProvider: AuthProvider;
        GithubAuthProvider: AuthProvider;
        OAuthProvider: AuthProvider;
        TwitterAuthProvider: AuthProvider;
        FacebookAuthProvider: AuthProvider;
        PhoneAuthState: {
          CODE_SENT: string;
          AUTO_VERIFY_TIMEOUT: string;
          AUTO_VERIFIED: string;
          ERROR: string;
        };
      }
```

How can I mock the FacebookAuthProvider property and avoid it being undefined for credential?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is a bit older, I stumbled across the same challenge and I could solve it like so:

Create default mock of the auth module in your project root

```
// file: __mocks__/@react-native-firebase/auth/index.js

const auth = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  onUserChanged: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => {}),
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn(),
  signInWithCredential: jest.fn(),
  // more functions from the module you want to use in your tests
});

auth.FacebookAuthProvider = {
  credential: jest.fn(),
};

export default auth;
```

Then, in your test file

```
describe('auth', () => {
  let authMock: jest.Mocked<ReturnType<typeof firebaseAuth>>;
  let facebookAuthProviderMock: jest.Mocked<FirebaseAuthTypes.AuthProvider>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    authMock = firebaseAuth() as jest.Mocked<ReturnType<typeof firebaseAuth>>;
    facebookAuthProviderMock = firebaseAuth.FaceAuthProviderMock as jest.Mocked<FirebaseAuthTypes.AuthProvider>;
  });

  it('your test', () => {
  // given
    authMock.signInWithCredential.mockResolvedValue({});
    facebookAuthProviderMock.credential.mockReturnValue({});

  // ...

  // then
  expect(authMock.signInWithCredential).toHaveBeenCalledWith({});
  })
})
```